# Flutter - DropdownButtonFormField value not updating

Tags: dart, flutter

My Dropdown button value doesn't update until the AlertDialog box is closed and reopened.

I have the variable set at the top of my class

```dart
class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  int _ratingController;
...

}
```

Within the class I have an AlertDialog that opens a form, within here I have the DropdownButtonFormField

```dart
AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: _eateryController,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(labelText: 'Eatery', hintText: 'eg Pizza Hut'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _supplierController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Supplier', hintText: 'eg Deliveroo'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _descriptionController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Description', hintText: 'eg cheese pizza'),
          ),
          DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
            value: _ratingController,
            items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(label.toString()),
                      value: label,
                    ))
                .toList(),
            hint: Text('Rating'),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _ratingController = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _handleSubmit(_eateryController.text, _supplierController.text,
                _descriptionController.text, _ratingController);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Save'),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('Cancel'),
        )
      ],
    );
```

the setState doesn't seem to be dynamically updating the fields value.  The updated value will only show once I close and re open the AlertDialog.

How can I get this to update instantly?

Thanks

Comment: which AlertDialog ? could you give us more information ?

Comment: AlertDialog is now showing in code block

Comment: that's because you are calling setState from the page which calls AlertDialog.  AlertDialog is stateless widget no stateful, you should wrap your DropdownButtonFormField in a StatefulWidget

Comment: Yes Its working now thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a new `StatefulWidget` class that should return your `AlertDialog`

```
class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {
  int _ratingController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: _eateryController,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration:
            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Eatery', hintText: 'eg Pizza Hut'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _supplierController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Supplier', hintText: 'eg Deliveroo'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _descriptionController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Description', hintText: 'eg cheese pizza'),
          ),
          DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
            value: _ratingController,
            items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(label.toString()),
              value: label,
            ))
                .toList(),
            hint: Text('Rating'),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _ratingController = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _handleSubmit(_eateryController.text, _supplierController.text,
                _descriptionController.text, _ratingController);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Save'),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text('Cancel'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

Use it like this

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return MyDialog();
  },
);
```

Comment: You save my day

Comment: @CopsOnRoad "value: _ratingController," confused me that how can we pass a controller instance to value attribute. Kindly update your answer to "value: _ratingControllerValue,". Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh The OP used `int` for `_ratingController`, so to answer him I had to use the same semantics. I understand the controller could be confusing but it's just an `int` value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use statefulBuilder inside alert dialog.

````
return AlertDialog(
                                      title: new Text('Table'),
                                      content: StatefulBuilder(builder:
                                          (BuildContext context,
                                              StateSetter setState) {
                                        return Container(
                                          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                            child: new Column(
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                                  value: dropdownValue,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black87),
                                                  items: <String>[
                                                    'Lot 1',
                                                    'Lot 2',
                                                    'Lot 3',
                                                    'Lot 4',
                                                  ].map<
                                                          DropdownMenuItem<
                                                              String>>(
                                                      (String value) {
                                                    return DropdownMenuItem<
                                                        String>(
                                                      value: value,
                                                      child: Text(value),
                                                    );
                                                  }).toList(),
                                                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      dropdownValue = newValue;
                                                    });
                                                  },
                                                ),
```
````

Comment: Just wanted to thank you very much as this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're calling `setState` in a wrong widget. The `AlertDialog` doesn't belong to `ItemList`'s tree because it's located inside another `Route`. So calling `setState` inside `_ItemListState` won't rebuild the `AlertDialog`.

Consider pulling out content of `AlertDialog` into a separate `StatefulWidget` and putting `int _ratingController` into it's state.